Reducing computational time in R code due to accessing elements
I am trying to reduce the computational time of an R code. I figured out that a part of it was coming from accessing a small number of rows of a large matrix. So I am creating a mwe to explain.
I have a matrix mt of dimension 100000 x 20. I have a list nbr that has 100000 elements, each of it a vector of length 500, and are subsets of 1:100000 (Note that in my original code, the vectors in nbr are not of exactly the same length, but I am making them for this example. So I couldn't save nbr as a matrix). I am looping over the elements of nbr, and for each x, I compute which.min(colSums(mt[x,])). Here is a code to recreate.
mt <- matrix(runif(100000 * 20), ncol = 20)
nbr <- lapply(1:100000, function(i) sample.int(100000, 500)) #takes 10-15 seconds

p1 <- proc.time()
out <- sapply(nbr, function(x) {
  which.min(colSums(mt[x,]))
})
p2 <- proc.time()
p2 - p1

This takes about 50-60 seconds to run on my computer. Note that, even if I had fixed indices 1:500 instead of x, then also it takes about 25-30 seconds to run, so the time consumption is not entirely coming from accessing elements of nbr. But for fixed indices, I would compute the submatrix beforehand. Anyway, now, the submatrix mt[x,] is of dimension 500 x 20 for all i. I found that if I just had a 500 x 20 matrix instead of mt[x,], it takes much less amount of time to run, like 3-4 seconds.
mt2 <- matrix(runif(500 * 20), ncol = 20)

p1 <- proc.time()
out <- sapply(1:100000, function(i) {
  which.min(colSums(mt2))
})
p2 <- proc.time()
p2 - p1

So a lot of the time is being spent for accessing rows of mt and elements of nbr. Is there anyway I could reduce this time, make it closer to what it actually for a 500 x 20 matrix?

set.seed(42)
mt <- matrix(runif(100000 * 20), ncol = 20)
nbr <- lapply(1:100000, function(i) sample.int(100000, 500)) #takes 10-15 seconds

p1 <- proc.time()
out <- sapply(nbr, function(x) {
  which.min(colSums(mt[x,]))
})
p2 <- proc.time()
p2 - p1
# user  system elapsed 
#18.86    0.97   19.84  

library(data.table)
system.time({
  
l <- lengths(nbr)
vnbr <- do.call(c, nbr)

DT <- data.table(mt)
DT <- DT[vnbr] #do all subsets at once
DT[, g := rep(seq_along(nbr), l)] #add grouping ID for the subsets
DTagg <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = g] #column sums by group
out1 <- melt(DTagg, id.vars = "g")[, which.min(value), by = g][["V1"]] #melt and which.min

})
# user  system elapsed 
#16.85    1.45    2.94 

Note that data.table uses internal parallelization. That explains the timing above.
getDTthreads()
#[1] 8

all.equal(out, out1)
#[1] TRUE

You could also try to simply parallelize your sapply loop.

Great! This indeed works. I found a code written in C and ran using the inline package, which also reduces the time drastically but doesn't use any parallelization.

Below is an option that uses sparse matrices and max.col after matrix multiplication.
We can save some time by creating nbr in parallel:
mt <- matrix(runif(100000 * 20), ncol = 20)

# not in parallel
system.time(nbr <- lapply(1:100000, function(i) sample.int(100000, 500)))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    9.55    8.02   17.58

library(parallel)

system.time({
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
  nbr <- parLapply(cl, 1:100000, function(i) sample.int(100000, 500))
  stopCluster(cl)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.35    0.45    7.33

As a side note, vapply is a little faster than sapply:
system.time(out1 <- sapply(nbr, \(x) which.min(colSums(mt[x,]))))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   13.70    2.39   16.14
system.time(out1 <- vapply(nbr, \(x) which.min(colSums(mt[x,])), 0L))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   12.60    2.55   15.15

Putting nbr into a sparse matrix allows us to use matrix multiplication instead of colSums:
library(Matrix)

jblood <- function(mt, nbr) {
  n <- length(nbr)
  mnbr <- sparseMatrix(unlist(nbr), rep(1:n, lengths(nbr)),
                       dims = c(nrow(mt), n))
  max.col(-crossprod(mnbr, mt), "first")
}

out2 <- jblood(mt, nbr)

identical(out1, out2)
#> [1] TRUE

The timings are a little slower than @Roland's data.table solution, but more memory efficient:
library(data.table)

Roland <- function(mt, nbr) {
  l <- lengths(nbr)
  vnbr <- do.call(c, nbr)
  
  DT <- data.table(mt)
  DT <- DT[vnbr] #do all subsets at once
  DT[, g := rep(seq_along(nbr), l)] #add grouping ID for the subsets
  DTagg <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = g] #column sums by group
  melt(DTagg, id.vars = "g")[, which.min(value), by = g][["V1"]] #melt and which.min
}

bench::mark(
  jblood = jblood(mt, nbr),
  Roland = Roland(mt, nbr),
  iterations = 10
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 jblood        4.54s    4.72s     0.206    1.72GB    0.103
#> 2 Roland        3.48s    4.17s     0.242    9.22GB    0.725


Update
Below, I run a couple tests on the memory constraints of the two approaches in response to the comment by @MikaelJagan.

500K rows
mt <- matrix(runif(5e5 * 20), ncol = 20)

system.time({
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
  nbr <- parLapply(cl, 1:5e5, function(i) sample.int(5e5, 500))
  stopCluster(cl)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    2.22    1.14  118.97

bench::mark(
  jblood = jblood(mt, nbr),
  Roland = Roland(mt, nbr)
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 jblood          38s      38s   0.0263     8.61GB   0.0263
#> 2 Roland        1.84m    1.84m   0.00908    46.1GB   0.0363


1M rows
mt <- matrix(runif(1e6 * 20), ncol = 20)

system.time({
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
  nbr <- parLapply(cl, 1:1e6, function(i) sample.int(1e6, 500))
  stopCluster(cl)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    4.09    2.20  433.93

system.time(out1 <- Roland(mt, nbr))
#> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.9 Gb
#> Timing stopped at: 52.27 174.7 130.8
gc()
#>             used   (Mb)  gc trigger    (Mb)    max used    (Mb)
#> Ncells   2680424  143.2     8920964   476.5     4688247   250.4
#> Vcells 273956809 2090.2 10124352670 77242.7 10544463963 80447.9
system.time(out2 <- jblood(mt, nbr))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   88.06    4.06   92.57


A couple of comments ...  (1) A cognitive simplification might be to switch i and j and reverse dims in the sparseMatrix call, then use %*% instead of crossprod.  (2) The profiler tracks memory on R's heap, but SuiteSparse does not use R's heap.  It's conceivable that more memory is used.  Still +1!

(1) Interesting you should note that. Before posting the answer, I benchmarked both %*% and crossprod (after swapping i and j), and crossprod in this instance was consistently a little faster, but that may be machine-dependent. (2) I did not know that. I updated the answer with a couple more runs that push the memory limits of my machine. Watching the system memory usage, the data.table approach clearly suffers from memory constraints (almost immediately gobbling up all the available memory), but the sparse matrix approach does not.
